# Spacing of prime in mathspec

Tags: spacing, xetex, symbols, opentype, mathspec

I'm using `mathspec` to typeset math in a non-Computer Modern OpenType font in XeLaTeX.

I have a permanent problem with the spacing of the prime symbol (the glyph of which is taken from the good old `cmsy7` font). As you can see in the two examples below, it is systematically too close to the preceding glyph:
[image]

and

[image]

I know that I can add spacing by a `\kern` command, but this not very elegant, and I can't do it all the time. I would have changed the widths of the glyphs of my OpenType font, but the problem comes rather from the position of the prime symbol in its box, and not from the ones of the letters. And I do not dare change the metrics of the `cmsy7` font (that would be the beginning of the end…).

I saw that `mathspec` provides a mechanism to add spacing to specific letters (Latin letters and some Greek ones), could we not use that mechanism to place some space in front of the prime symbol, in a systematic way?

Comment: just define `\prime` to be `\mkern1mu\originalprime` ?

Comment: Would you mind adding an example of code?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I wrote `\def\prime{\mkern1mu\originalprime}` and the prime disappeared. Are you sure `\originalprime` is defined?

Comment: @yannis sorry I meant after `\let\originalprime\prime` the usual idiom to save a definiion before redefining it.